# Restoring french polished buffet

Tags: furniture

I have a 90 year old mahogany buffet that needs a pretty solid restoration job. Some of the planks that make up its top have lifted by a few mil, but most of the work is simply cleaning it up. I'm not sure how the wood is finished, it seems french polished but I do not know much about 1920s furniture.

What is the best way to attack this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that your buffet is French Polished. French polishing is the technique of buffing in shellac mixed with alcohol and oil to a high gloss finish in many thin coats. If you attempt to sand down the differences in the slat matches, you will be in a situation to completely refinish the piece.  French polish can be easily touched up with a cloth pad and a mix of above ingredients, but refinishing from scratch using the French polish method is an art form and extremely time consuming. There is no way I know to even out the displacement of the planks without some precise sanding.   Good luck.